# to build a "quick" web backend for a mobile application, Ruby on Rails or Django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, mobile

I am currently in the process of building a mobile app, on iphone. I want the app to be able to connect to a web back-end server to manage user logins and to and retrieve user data. Which would be quicker/simpler to build that type of back-end RoR or Django?

Comment: Depends on the programmer(s) skills, ability to learn, existing knowledge, and mind-set, etc. "Fastest" may be Java Servlets to some people. There are also *many* other "rapid-prototype/agile" web-stacks out there written (multiple times) in just about every language. Also, a "blog in 5 minutes" screencast doesn't mean your app will be anywhere near ready in 5 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer about Django, but if you want to write it in Ruby, you should consider using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) as a lightweight alternative to Rails.

Comment: I was wondering about Sinatra, what are the advantages over RoR?

Comment: Basically it's just closer to the metal. The framework itself is very basic and relies on you to add things as you need them, as opposed to the Rails approach of giving you everything in case you need it.

Comment: Would web2py be a good alternative?

Answer (score 6):

Go with whichever you are most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose django and are planning on handling RESTful requests from the phone, you should look into [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home).